# How to get the 10 highest values from a CSV file using Python without Pandas

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file, and I turn this file into a dictionary using the DictReader from the CSV library.

My code is like that:

```py
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        highest = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: (x['value']))
        print(highest)
```

But this is don't working and the list `highest` have all the data from the CSV and I only want the 10 highest values. But I don't know how to use limit the list to receive only the 10 highest values using dictionary.

**I can't use Pandas**

Comment: Meta: Not that there's anything wrong with Pandas, but it does surprise me how many people have forgotten how to write Python without it! The Python standard library contains a wealth of tools for manipulating data and many of us got along just fine for many years before Pandas ever existed. I feel like these days Pandas is getting treated like [jQuery once was](https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) on Stack Overflow...

Comment: I agree. I was one of that people, and I was having so very difficulty to do things without Pandas and Numpy. We have to understand how these big libraries works before doing everything with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice the list after sorting to get the 10 highest values:

```
highest = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: x['value'])[-10:]
```

You can also use the `heapq.nlargest` method to achieve the same in *O(n log t)* 
 (where `t` is the number of items to return) time complexity instead of *O(n log n)*:

```
import heapq
highest = heapq.nlargest(10, reader, key=lambda x: x['value'])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. But I didn't understand why the "-10". Could you explain?

Comment: Glad to be of help. I'm using `-10` as the starting index to slice the sorted list because you're sorting the list in the ascending order, so the last 10 items would be the highest.